# Unable to see network drive Win 10

Tags: networking, network-shares

This is crazy and I'm starting to lose my mind.

I have a Network Media device (Called - X3D) (it's an old one, but works well)... I have two External Hard Drives connected to it. This is shared over the Home network.

My Mobile phone can access the HDDs. My Desktop computer can access the HDDs. My Laptop can Access the HDDs.

My other Laptop (Moms Laptop) **can not** see the Drives.

It can see and access ALL other devices on the network without issue.

When I click on Network in File (Windows) Explorer...

I can see all Network devices except X3D.

**Now here's the clincher:**

- I can Ping it.
- I can see it under 'Media Devices'
- I can see it under 'Other Devices'
- I can even access the Media via the dreaded Windows Media Player. *Going to extremes now*.

But for the life of me can't see it as a Network Computer or Map the Drives to access the files themselves. If I try Map it, it's not listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old network disk device might be using the SMB version 1
network protocol, which is disabled by default in newer Windows versions.

Run from the Start menu "Turn Windows features on or off"
and enable this feature:

[image]

Comment: +1 because I'm fairly sure this is the issue, but it would help a lot to also write down what you have to check. You know, novice user will get confused here.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much... This was perfect and the best most simple answer.